# Cannot detect click on link in table

Tags: javascript, html, ruby-on-rails-4

I am trying to detect a click on a link  in a table td element , the alert is not raised on click

I added a js file in my assets and added the require in my application.js

```
application.js
...
//= require albums

albums.js
$(function() {
   $("#owners  tr td a").click(function() {
    return alert(clicked);
   });
 });
```

the html is inside a modal window

```
<div class="modal-body-content" id="myModalBody" style="display: block;">
    <div id="owner_list">
        <div class="pagination pull-right">
            <ul class="pagination pagination-sd">
                <li class="page active">
                <a data-remote="true" href="#">1</a>
                </li>
                <li class="page">
                    <a data-remote="true" href="/backoffice/users.js?locale=fr&amp;page=2" rel="next">2</a>
                </li>
                <li class="next pagination">
                    <a data-remote="true" href="/backoffice/users.js?locale=fr&amp;page=2" rel="next">suiv.</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="table_responsive">
            <table class="container table" id="owners">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Adresse courriel</td>
                        <td>Identifiant</td>
                        <td>Prénom</td>
                        <td>Nom</td>
                    </tr>
                </thead>

                <tbody>
                    <tr class="clear">
                        <td><a href="#">active.memory@example.com</a></td>
                        <td><a href="#">active_memory</a></td>
                        <td>Active</td>
                        <td>Memory</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr class="clear">
                        <td><a href="#">albert.camus@example.com</a></td>
                        <td><a href="#">albert</a></td>
                        <td>n/a</td>
                        <td>n/a</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr class="clear">
                        <td><a href="#">arthur.rubinstein@example.com</a></td>
                        <td><a href="#">arthur</a></td>
                        <td>n/a</td>
                        <td>n/a</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr class="clear">
                        <td><a href="#">debbie.kind@example.com</a></td>
                        <td><a href="#">debbie</a></td>
                        <td>Debbie</td>
                        <td>Elkind</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr class="clear">
                        <td><a href="#">sergio.mendez@example.com</a></td>
                        <td><a href="#">sergio</a></td>
                        <td>n/a</td>
                        <td>n/a</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

what mistake did I do ?

Answer (score 0):

I modified the javascript , and it now runs very well :

```
$(document).on('click', '#owners  tr td a', function(e) {
  alert('clicked');
  e.preventDefault();
  return e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Comment: In fact, you can leave only `#owners a` here.